# Erroneous Return Value in Excel 2010 Lookup

Tags: excel-2010

I created a lookup table which serves as a transmutation tool for students' grades. Here's a link of the [Excel Sheet](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/32739964/Transmutation.xlsx) for reference.

The structure may look  weird because there may be multiple lookup values which should return the same value. Now looking at the linked excel sheet, my question is why searching for a perfect score will NOT return a perfect transmutation grade (highlighted cells). Every other lookup value seems to get an accurate return value.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LOOKUP` required the lookup vector to be in ascending order.  Your data deviates from this starting at row 102

Form Excell Help

> Important  The values in lookup_vector must be placed in ascending order: ..., -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, ..., A-Z, FALSE, TRUE; otherwise, LOOKUP might not return the correct value. Uppercase and lowercase text are equivalent

An alternative formula would be

```
=INDEX(Trans!A:A,MATCH(A2,Trans!E:E,0))
```